# Umbraco, razor and image gallery

Tags: razor, umbraco

I am new to Umbraco. I am creating an image gallery (called Customers). A Customer has a logo, which is an image.

[image: My Umbraco Content]

How do I create a razor macro that outputs a list of customer logos?

I am after the cshtml code, probably something like this:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@foreach (var customer in Content.Customers) {
  <img src="@customer.logo.umbracoFile" alt="@customer.Name"/>
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that works

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@foreach (var customer in Model.NodeById(1062).Children) {
  <img src="@umbraco.IO.IOHelper.ResolveUrl(customer.logo)" alt="@customer.Name"/>
}
```

Comment: It usually is not a good idea to use node id's - if you recreate the node, the id will probably be different. You can use `Model.Customer` to get all children having the content type `Customer` (I updated my answer)

Comment: you can use macro parameter option to choose the node

Comment: What is a macro parameter option and/or how do you use it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the script executes on the *Customers* page, and that the content type containing log and url is called *Customer*:

```
@foreach(var customer in Model.Customer)
{
    <img src="@customer.Media("logo", "umbracoFile")" alt="@customer.Name"/>
}
```

`Model.Customer` will give you a list of all children of the current page which are `Customer`s (content type).

Comment: I partially solved the problem. You need to replace Content.Customers with Model.NodeById(1062).Children. And I could get the URL, which is customer.logo, it outputs something like ~/media/105/ozmosis.jpg, but Url.Content doesn't work to resolve the tilde

Comment: oh sorry, I only looked at the code to get the url of the media file, I'll update...

Comment: Thanks Marapet. No, Customers is actually not a page (see my screenshot), and Customer's can be put in any page. That's why I had to use NodeById. Any better way?

Answer (score 0):

for using a dynamic location (macro parameters), you could do two things:

**1. setting this in your root document so the user can change the customer slider location (if you would like that):**

```
var RootNode = @Model.NodeById(@Model.AncestorOrSelf(1).HeaderRoot);
```

Where HeaderRoot is the name of a property on your starting file (root)

**2. Using a parameter on your razor script**

```
var rootNode = @Parameter.RootNode;
```

and use it something like:

```
@Model.NodeById(rootNode).Children();
```

so in your code, it would look something like this (not tested):

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

@{ var rootNode = @Parameter.RootNode;}
@foreach (var customer in Model.NodeById(rootNode).Children()) {
  <img src="@umbraco.IO.IOHelper.ResolveUrl(customer.logo)" alt="@customer.Name"/>
}
```